# Quickbooks Online - Customer Query Using Email (QBXML)

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Can't we query Quickbooks for a Customer using the Email address? 
I came to know that the only way to query using Email is to query using FullName and then parse the response at your own end to match the Email address. 
And this seems true as  is not working within .

Why is this so? If we can query using  then why can't using .

I just came to know about a "not so good" solution which is to store Email address in FullName field of QuickBooks Online and then make simple Query for customer using FullName. The drawback in this solution is that FullName's maximum length is 41 but I think Email addresses can exceed the 41 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can't we query Quickbooks for a Customer using the Email address?

Nope. QuickBooks does not support this.

If you want to query by the `Email` field, you'll need to pull the entire customer list (or find some other way to filter it down) and filter it within your application.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, in QBO API v3.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE PrimaryEmailAddr = 'your-name@example.com'
```

It's undocumented, but I've been using it in production for a few years.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/Customer

Answer (score 0):

No, we can't query Quickbooks (QBO) for a Customer using the Email address, you have only filter options, please follow URL for reference, https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/customer. If you are having such requirement then fetch all the Customers at the starting of the your app, keep it in cache file and use it, specify cache duration as per your requirement.

Thanks,

Reshma D.

Comment: He's asking about QuickBooks for Windows, not QuickBooks Online.